# Laravel 5 mutators only work when I create a record and not when I update a record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mutators

Hi I have created a mutator to only store digits on my phone numbers. Here is my code in my Profile Model.

```
public function setPhoneAttribute($phone)
{
    $this->attributes['phone'] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$phone);
}
```

This works when I create a new record, but if I update the record it does not work. My question is how do I execute the Mutator on both create and update?

Here is how I update and create in my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Profile;

class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function create(ProfileRequest $request)
    {
        // Check if the user does not have a profile yet
        if(!Auth::user()->profile()->first()){

            // Save to database
            $saveToDatabase = Auth::user()->profile()->create($request->all()); 

            return $saveToDatabase;
        }
    }

    public function update(Profile $profile, ProfileRequest $request)
    {

        // Save to database
        $saveToDatabase = Auth::user()->profile()->update($request->all());

        return $saveToDatabase;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code that shows how you update/create the record

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

`Auth::user()->profile()->create($request->all())` calls the `create` method on your relationship (`HasOneOrMany`). This method then creates a **new instance of the related model**. This is important because obviously attribute mutators are only used when the record is created *through the model*.

However the relationship object doesn't have any `update` method. (It also wouldn't make sense to have one...). So what's happening instead is, when you do `Auth::user()->profile()->update($request->all())`. The `update` call get's proxied off to a query builder instance (that matches the relationship). This results in something like this being executed:

```
UPDATE profiles SET foo = 'bar' WHERE [relationship conditions]
```

**It doesn't use the model at all**. Therefore the mutator doesn't work.

Instead you have to call the `update` method on the actual related model. You can access it by just calling the relation as a property like this:

```
$saveToDatabase = Auth::user()->profile->update($request->all());
//                                    ^^
//                               no parentheses
```

---

If the `Profile` model is injected correctly you actually might also just use that though:

```
public function update(Profile $profile, ProfileRequest $request)
{
    // Save to database
    $saveToDatabase = $profile->update($request->all());
    return $saveToDatabase;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this makes a lot of sense. This fixed my issue:

    $saveToDatabase = $profile->update($request->all());

Answer (score 1):

Using this code instead of your code

```
$saveToDatabase = Auth::user()->profile->update($request->all());
```