# Laravel Defining A Mutator

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserInformation extends Model {

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = "user_information";

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'img_path',
        'born',
        'gender',
        'address',
        'country_id',
        'about',
        'institution',
        'area_of_expertise',
        'cv_path',
        'facebook',
        'twitter',
        'instagram',
        'linkedin',
        'university',
        'university_graduated_at',
        'md',
        'md_graduated_at',
        'associate_professor',
        'associate_professor_graduated_at'
    ];

    public function setBornAttribute($date) {
        $this->attributes['born'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Error :

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value:
>   '26/10/1988' for column 'born' at row 1 (SQL: update
>   `user_information`

How to update :

```
public function updateUser($request, $id) {
        $user = User::with('userInformation')->findOrFail($id);
        $user->update(array_filter($request->all()));
        $user->userInformation()->update(array_filter($request->only([
            'title',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'img_path',
            'born',
            'gender',
            'address',
            'country_id',
            'about',
            'institution',
            'area_of_expertise',
            'cv_path',
            'facebook',
            'twitter',
            'instagram',
            'linkedin',
            'university',
            'university_graduated_at',
            'md',
            'md_graduated_at',
            'associate_professor',
            'associate_professor_graduated_at'
        ]), 'strlen'));

        return User::with('userInformation')->findOrFail($id);
    }
```

I send the born date d/m/Y format from user interface. When i store this data in mysql, i ve to reformat to Y-m-d..

I googled and found the mutators : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators

I added setNameAttribute function to UserInformation model. And i refreshed the page then tried again. But nothing changed. I got the same error.

How can i fix this problem ?

**p.s. : I am using Laravel 5.3**

Comment: you should convert it to Y-m-d before storing to db

Answer (score 1):

Use carbon `parse`.

```
public function setBornAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['born'] = Carbon::parse($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the property ***$dateFormat*** on your model as follow:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
```

[Check the documentation about date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

Change the set function to:

```
public function setBornAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['born'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: I debugged the code ... getBornAttribute calls but setBornAttribute does not call when update.

Comment: how you set the value of born? if you are using the `fill` function it will not execute, you should use `$model->born = $value;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

[Laravel 5 mutators only work when I create a record and not when I update a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306890/laravel-5-mutators-only-work-when-i-create-a-record-and-not-when-i-update-a-reco)

I changed the `$user->userInformation()->update(` to `$user->userInformation->update(` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has native support for date fields. Try this instead:

```
class UserInformation extends Model {

  protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'born'
 ];

 //Rest of model without mutator

}
```